# How to this python-spotify-recommendation question?

Tags: python, spotify, recommendation-engine

I'm trying to make my recommendation list using [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/yamaerenay/spotify-dataset-19212020-600k-tracks?resource=download&select=tracks.csv).

I want to group songs by artists_upd、id and artists in order.
The original one is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtLwh.png)
and I want to make it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUdIA.png)
but I failed and it showed keyerror 'artists' and I can't understand why?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
import re 
import sys
import itertools

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import spotipy.util as util

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
%matplotlib inline

from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:90% !important; }</style>"))

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option("max_rows", None)

spotify_df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/tracksong/tracks.csv')
spotify_df.head()

data_w_genre = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/tracksong/artists.csv')
data_w_genre.head()

spotify_df['artists_upd_v1'] = spotify_df['artists'].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r"'([^']*)'", x))
spotify_df['artists_upd_v1'].values[0][0]

spotify_df[spotify_df['artists_upd_v1'].apply(lambda x: not x)].head(5)

spotify_df['artists_upd_v2'] = spotify_df['artists'].apply(lambda x: re.findall('\"(.*?)\"',x))
spotify_df['artists_upd'] = np.where(spotify_df['artists_upd_v1'].apply(lambda x: not x), spotify_df['artists_upd_v2'], spotify_df['artists_upd_v1'] )


spotify_df['artists_song'] = spotify_df.apply(lambda row: row['artists_upd'][0]+str(row['name']),axis = 1)
#original code is -> spotify_df['artists_song'] = spotify_df.apply(lambda row: row['artists_upd'][0]+row['name'],axis = 1)

spotify_df.sort_values(['artists_song','release_date'], ascending = False, inplace = True)

spotify_df[spotify_df['name']=='Adore You']

spotify_df.drop_duplicates('artists_song',inplace = True)

spotify_df[spotify_df['name']=='Adore You']

artists_exploded = spotify_df[['artists_upd','id']].explode('artists_upd')

artists_exploded_enriched = artists_exploded.merge(data_w_genre, how = 'left', left_on = 'artists_upd',right_on = 'artists')
```

`KeyError: 'artists'`

Here is [my code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1d_aj60ddUhO_M_TnD68GaN2uEWbnoI0a?usp=sharing) (last line) and here is the [original code](https://github.com/madhavthaker/spotify-recommendation-system/blob/main/spotify-recommendation-engine.ipynb) (line 25).

Comment: @medium-dimensional thank u sir! I repost it.

Comment: Ok ! I repost it again. If you need more information plz let me know. Thank you@medium-dimensional :D

Comment: sure! That's better. Thank u~ :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are attempting to merge on the `artists` column of `data_w_genre` (with the parameter `right_on = 'artists'`), but `data_w_genre` does not have a column with that name.

```
 artists_exploded_enriched = artists_exploded.merge(data_w_genre, how = 'left', left_on = 'artists_upd',right_on = 'artists')
```

In the original code, the csv file from which `data_w_genre` is imported has an `artists` column:

```
 data_w_genre.dtypes
```

in Cell 9 outputs:

```
artists              object
acousticness        float64
danceability        float64
duration_ms         float64
energy              float64
instrumentalness    float64
liveness            float64
loudness            float64
speechiness         float64
tempo               float64
valence             float64
popularity          float64
key                   int64
mode                  int64
count                 int64
genres               object
dtype: object
```

But the same line in Cell 9 in your code outputs:

```
id             object
followers     float64
genres         object
name           object
popularity    float64
dtype: object
```

Note that `artists` is missing. Without an `artists` column in `data_w_genre`, you won't be able to reproduce the line from the original code. I would look into where the original author sourced 'data_w_genre.csv' and try to obtain or create a file with the same format.

Comment: ooh! I see..that's why! Now I change data_w_genre.cvs to spotify.cvs becaus the original 'data_w_genre.csv' is gone...but I will try if this work. Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad it helped! Please accept the answer if it answered your question. Thanks.